# Выполнить case в запросе

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

Как выполнить кейс в запросе, нужно это поместить в функцию?

```
case when (select "set" from "OrderList" where id_order=8 and id = 2)=true then
(delete from "orderList" where id_order=8 and id_parents = 2)
(update "OrderList" set id_parents = 0,hash_product='hash_product1','name_product1',id_type_parent=2,name_type_parent='name_type_parent1',id_type=2,name_type = 'sadasd',parameters=array[2,3,1,4,6,4,3],"set"=false,finished=false where id_order=8 and id = 2)
else
(update "OrderList" set id_parents = 0,hash_product='hash_product1','name_product1',id_type_parent=2,name_type_parent='name_type_parent1',id_type=2,name_type = 'sadasd',parameters=array[2,3,1,4,6,4,3],"set"=false,finished=false where id_order=8 and id = 2)
end
```

Comment: Да в функцию/процедуру и использовать не case, а IF из pl/sql

Comment: case - ставится в select и предполагает "скалярный" результат как на трёх входах так и на выходе. В програмном потоке используется if

Answer (score 1):

Для привыкшего к императивному программированию - использовать хранимую процедуру будет проще. Вам вроде бы ничего их функции возвращать не надо, поэтому для этого даже не обязательно создавать хранимку явно, `postgresql` умеет анонимные блоки кода [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html):

```
do language plpgsql $func$
begin 
if exists (select 1 from "OrderList" where id_order=8 and id = 2 and "set"=true) then
    delete from "orderList" where id_order=8 and id_parents = 2;
    update "OrderList" set id_parents = 0,hash_product='hash_product1','name_product1',id_type_parent=2,name_type_parent='name_type_parent1',id_type=2,name_type = 'sadasd',parameters=array[2,3,1,4,6,4,3],"set"=false,finished=false where id_order=8 and id = 2;
else
    update "OrderList" set id_parents = 0,hash_product='hash_product1','name_product1',id_type_parent=2,name_type_parent='name_type_parent1',id_type=2,name_type = 'sadasd',parameters=array[2,3,1,4,6,4,3],"set"=false,finished=false where id_order=8 and id = 2
end if; 
end
$func$
```

Либо использовать декларативную логику SQL и описать, что должно получиться. У вас, возможно по ошибке, update в обеих ветках условия идентичен. Задачу можно решить универсальным способом сделать что угодно одним запросом - через CTE.

```
with orderset_exists as (
    select id from "OrderList" 
    where id_order=8 and id = 2 and "set" = true
), orderset_delete as (
    delete from "orderList" where id_order=8 and id_parents in (select id from orderset_exists)
)
update "OrderList" set id_parents = 0,hash_product='hash_product1','name_product1',id_type_parent=2,name_type_parent='name_type_parent1',id_type=2,name_type = 'sadasd',parameters=array[2,3,1,4,6,4,3],"set"=false,finished=false where id_order=8 and id = 2
```

Comment: WITH мне нравится, то что надо, спасибо.
`with orderset_exists as (
    select id from "OrderList" 
    where id_order=8 and id = 2 and "set" = true
), orderset_delete as (
    delete from "OrderList" where id_order=8 and id_parents in (select id from orderset_exists)
)
update "OrderList" set id_parents = 0,hash_product='hash_product1',name_product='name_product1',id_type_parent=2,name_type_parent='name_type_parent1',id_type=2,name_type = 'sadasd',parameters=array[2,3,1,4,6,4,3],"set"=false,finished=false where id_order=8 and id = 2`

Answer (score 1):

`declare 
id number;
begin
select "set" 
into id 
from "OrderList" 
where id_order=8 and id = 2;
 delete from "orderList" where id_order=8 and id_parents = 2;
 update "OrderList" set id_parents = 0,hash_product='hash_product1' ...
exception 
when no_data_found then 
 update "OrderList" set id_parents = 0,hash_product='hash_product1' ...
end;`